# QTreeView with QAbstractItemModel: tree items collapse and expend when adding/updating new children

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a QTreeView with my own model. When adding new items into the tree, some items expand or collapse. How can I preserve the expand state when modifying the tree?

Thank you, Martin.

Comment: How do you modify your tree?

Comment: I call beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), iRow, iRow); then I update data and finally call endInsertRows();

Comment: Ok... could you show some code?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite late for the question's author but I had a similar problem and ended up here, so maybe it is worth posting a solution I came up with.

My understanding is that updating nodes is not a problem - indices are not invalidated and expansion is conserved. When you add a new node, however, the default seems to be to make the node collapsed. The fallowing small hack changes the default to expand all newly added indices:

```
// This is done at the point where the model is set to be used by the view
connect(&model, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted,
        [&](const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last) {
          for (; first <= last; ++first) {
            tree_view->expand(
                model.index(first, 0, parent));
          }
        });
```

In case you want to replace a node with a new version (remove it and add a new one in its place) you can use a similar approach: remember expansion by connecting to `QAbstractItemModel::rowsAboutToBeRemoved` and using `QTreeView::isExpanded()`. The state can be resored in a function/slot connected to `QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share some code, but it is too long. I will explain where my problem was instead.

This is my tree structure

[image]

It is necessary to use following functions when inserting/deleting rows.

```
void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows(const QModelIndex & parent, int first, int last);
void QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows()

void QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveRows(const QModelIndex & parent, int first, int last)
void QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows()
```

I found out that when inserting/deleting items A and C, it is required to use invalid model index as a parent index. An invalid model index is QModelIndex() without any parameters. At least it is what help in my case.

A simple tree model example is available here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html